# vim line number does weird things on lines starting with an 8

Tags: external-command, line-numbers

I have some commands set up that run the test under my current cursor position. using the command `rails test <filename>:<linenumber>`. I execute this command through
`exec '!rails test %:'.line('.')` which works fine in most situations. However, for some reason when the line number starts with an `8` it behaves weirdly.

when testing with the command `:exec '!echo "%:'.line('.').'"'` i get the following outputs

```
line  7 -> test.txt:7
line  8 -> test.txt
line  9 -> test.txt:9
line 79 -> test.txt:79
line 80 -> test.txt0
line 89 -> test.txt9
line 90 -> test.txt:90
```

Even when hardcoding the number in the command it behaves similarly

`!echo "%:80"` results in `test.txt0`
Hardcoding the filename does get the correct result though `!echo "test.txt:80"` -> `test.txt:80`

This pattern repeats for the 800s as well.
Am i missing something obvious?

I tried running the same test in `vim --clean` to make sure there weren't any plugins messing with me but it has the same behavior

Comment: `Am I missing something obvious?` `:h filename-modifiers`

Comment: Thanks @Matt, i was missing something obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would propose is:

```
:exec '!echo "' . expand(%) . ':' . line('.') . '"'
```

What @Matt highlight is that:

```
expand('%:8')
```

Returns the 8.3 version of the current filename.